# Bootstrap navbar collapse doesn't work

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I can't find the reason why, when trying to use the navbar button from Bootstrap, it doesn't work.

I think it has something to do with my page loading the jQuery library or something, though I don't understand.

Here is my code. I'll show just the head and navbar parts since I believe there's where the problem lives. Everything else is simple HTML structure:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1">
    <!--Boostrap jQuery-->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjsmfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!--Boostrap-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u"
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    <!--Favicon-->
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="media/favicon-32x32.png" sizes="32x32" />
    <!--Mi CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="index.css">

    <!-- p5.js-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.5.2/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/sketch.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

    <title>Festival Sonorum</title>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Navegación</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html">Festival Sonorum</a>
            </div>
            <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="programa.html">Programa</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#acerca">Acerca</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contacto">Contacto</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#galeria">Galería</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Artistas <span class="caret"></span></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                            <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>
    <!--fin del navbar-->
```

Am I missing something? Like loading a library?

Comment: Hi @dawn :) If you found my answer helpful, please [accept it & vote up](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Bootstrap does not include jQuery, so you need to add it yourself to make it work. Add it just before your bootstrap.js script.

As per [Bootstrap's docs](https://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/):

> *jQuery required*
>
> Please note that all JavaScript plugins require jQuery
>   to be included, as shown in the starter template. Consult our
>   bower.json to see which versions of jQuery are supported.

On top of that, the integrity check fails on your `bootstrap.min.js` script. To make it work you need to fix that and add at least version `1.9.0` of jQuery:

```
...
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!--Boostrap jQuery-->
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
...
```

Comment: Hi @dawn, apparently `bootstrap.min.js` was failing the cdn integrity check, thus never loading. I updated the answer and replaced the <script> tag for it, replace it too and you're good to go. Got it working [here](http://jsbin.com/yedumez/edit?html,output).

Comment: If in doubt next time, open your console  (On Chrome it's `Ctrl + Shift + J` for Windows or `Cmd + Opt + J` on Mac, might be different in your browser) and see the output. In this case, I could see the error: `Failed to find a valid digest in the 'integrity' attribute for resource 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js' with computed SHA-256 integrity 'U5ZEeKfGNOja007MMD3YBI0A3OSZOQbeG6z2f2Y0hu8='. The resource has been blocked.`

Answer (score 0):

You should check your bootstrap.css files in the head section, jquery.js before body closing tags, and you should give id to toggled nav same as button data-target.

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarToggleExternalContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">  
  <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
</button>
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
```